# Moddle Search and Replace Access Denied

Tags: moodle

After moving the moodle site together with moodledata into another directory and reconfiguring it to use another database. the last step, According to what I read, is to use the search and replace tool admin/tool/replace/index.php

however, when I run it, I got access denied, which is weird because I'm login as admin. What am I doing wrong? By the way, I'm using version 2.5

Comment: Can you enable debugging tools on your moodle setup `/admin/settings.php?section=debugging`, by setting debugdisplay to true, and debug to developer, and report any additional message?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have enough permission on database.